# Plotting characters distribution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot the distribution of characters in text in a column in pandas.
For example:

```
Phrase
example1
example1+example2
example 3 
example 4
example of sentence
and so on....
```

So I would need to determine the length of each string/text within the `Phrase` column.
To calculate the length of

```
df['Phrases length'] = df.Phrase.apply(len)
```

but then I realised that I do not know how to plot the length distribution.
I hope you can provide some help or advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally plot distributions with histograms. In your case it can be like so:

```
sns.displot(df,x='Phrases length')
```

Check out further documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html).

Comment: thanks delimiter. It is generating a lot of /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:238: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 9659 missing from current font. . Is it normal?

Comment: This is definitely not normal, and can be something specific to your environment, e.g. how your Matplotlib is installed.